After installing Ubuntu 24.04, why does my graphics card apparently get shut off?
My computer is a home built.  Intel Core i5-760, ASUS P7H55-M LX motherboard, AMD Radeon HD 6870 graphics card.
After installing Ubuntu 24.04 on an empty drive, when I try to boot it up, during the boot process, my screen goes black, and the hardware displays an error message to check the video cable.  This occurs just before the screen to log in to Ubuntu.
This also happens to my Ubuntu 22.04 installation if I allow certain updates to be installed.
Any idea what's causing it?
